DataTable not re-rendering after data update
I'm having trouble re-initializing a DataTable in my Vue.js app after updating the data. Here's my code:

template :

.
<table ref="tableUtamaAlamat" id="tableUtamaAlamat" class="display datatable-custom" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index) in tableDataUtamaAlamat" :key="index">
            <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.alamat }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


script part (methods):

initDataTableAlamat() {
   $(this.$refs.tableUtamaAlamat).DataTable({
       paging: true,
       searching: true,
       ordering: false,
       info: true,
       dom: '<"top-toolbar"fB>rt<"bottom-toolbar"ip><"clear">',
       buttons: [
           {
               text: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mr-2 h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4v16m8-8H4" /></svg>Tambah Alamat',
               action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                   $("#modalUtamaAlamat").removeClass("hidden");
               },
           },
       ],
       language: {
           search: "Pencarian:",
           lengthMenu: "Tampilkan _MENU_ entri",
           info: "Menampilkan _START_ sampai _END_ dari _TOTAL_ entri",
           infoEmpty: "Tidak ada entri tersedia",
           infoFiltered: "(difilter dari _MAX_ total entri)",
           zeroRecords: "Tidak ada entri yang cocok ditemukan",
           paginate: {
               next: "",
               previous: "",
           },
       },
       initComplete: function () {
           $(".wrapper-datatable-custom .top-toolbar .dt-search .dt-input").attr("placeholder", "Pilih salah satu...");
       },
   });
},

async getAlamatByUserID() {
    try {
        const payload = { user_id: this.$store.state.auth.user.user.user_id };
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch("vendor/getAlamatByUserID", payload);
        this.tableDataUtamaAlamat = response.data.data;
        // Re-initialize DataTable
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            const table = $(this.$refs.tableUtamaAlamat).DataTable();
            if (table) {
                table.destroy(); // Destroy the existing DataTable instance
            }
            this.initDataTableAlamat(); // Re-initialize DataTable
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching alamat:", error);
    }
},

async deleteAlamat(alamat_id){
    try {
        const payload = { alamat_id :  alamat_id}; // Assuming `this.form` is your form data object
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch('vendor/deleteAlamat', payload);
        console.log(response)
        await this.getAlamatByUserID(); // Fetch the updated address list
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving alamat:', error);
        return error;
        // throw error;
    }
}

explain :

so the idea is that, I want to re-initializing th datatable when action deleteAlamat is fired. As you can see, in this function I fired getAlamatByUserID function, which is updateing the data from this.tableDataUtamaAlamat. and yes, when I console.log itm the data is updated.

the problem is that, why the datatable is not rendering? when I fire the action delete, the total of row still persist. I have to refresh the page first to change the amount of row in front end


any suggesttion?
thank you in advance
EDIT :
I forgot to mention error, becaouse there is no error when re-initializing part
EDIT :
Ayyone?
i think the issue is related to async/await timing.
because, when I fetch the data with harcoded data the re-initializing is succeed.

is this vue2 or vue3?

you're on the right track by destroying the existing DataTable instance and then reinitializing it.
i would recommend using a setTimeout to give the DOM time to update before the DataTable is reinitialized.
Here’s an updated approach:
async getAlamatByUserID() {
    try {
        const payload = { user_id: this.$store.state.auth.user.user.user_id };
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch("vendor/getAlamatByUserID", payload);
        this.tableDataUtamaAlamat = response.data.data;

        this.$nextTick(() => {
            const table = $(this.$refs.tableUtamaAlamat).DataTable();
            if (table) {
                table.clear().destroy();
            }

     
            $(this.$refs.tableUtamaAlamat).find('tbody').empty();

            // Re-initialize the DataTable after a short delay
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.initDataTableAlamat(); 
            }, 100);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching alamat:", error);
    }
},


If i change like this,  the datatable is not initializing at all. I double check an do console.log inside setTimeout function. the console.log() is triggered, same as the function initDataTableAlamat. but strange, the datatable is not initializing. no error provided too

If I commented out the empty() part, the data when first reload is initializing. but then same, when take an action delete, the datatable is not -re-intializing
